# Looping over query results in Node, but I keep losing my loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, node-modules

Bit of background: I'm building a tool that will take screenshots of webpages on a schedule. It also has settings stored about how to take the screenshot (e.g. hide certain page elements, wait X seconds in case of long polling requests or splash pages that have animations)

So naturally, I have to read this stuff from a database, and loop over those results to run chunks of code based on these variables.

I can output my records just fine. I can loop over them individually just fine. But when I try to plug and play into an existing chunk of code, things break down. Somehow this is breaking my loop and the code further down the page does not recognize the variables from my database loop.

Assume my database records are assigned to the variable `poo` and that I am confident in my syntax before this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < poo.length; i++) {
    console.log('The name of this task is ' + poo[i].PrettyName); 

    //So far so good! I can output my column names as variables and do what I want with them.

    Screenshot(poo[i].URL);  
    //This works too!

    async function Screenshot(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   headless: true,
   defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080},
   args: [
   "--no-sandbox",
   "--disable-gpu",
   ]
 });

//This is not the end of my code, but basically nothing after this point works. 
//When I try to read or log any variable, 
//even ones that worked before, it tells me "cannot read property ___ of undefined."
```

Did I accidentally break my loop with a bracket somewhere? Is this async function wizardry? Misunderstanding when I have to apply callbacks?

The variables remain broken after this point even if I enter a manual delay of 10 seconds before the async function runs, which should be more than enough time to form a recordset for processing.

For reference the meat and potatoes of the code you see is the `puppeteer` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [a solution](https://old.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/a50jte/is_it_best_to_use_var_or_let_in_for_loop/) on my Google journey, thanks to Reddit user kranker.

> In any closures created in the loop, let variables will be bound to the value from only that iteration of the loop, whereas var variables will be the current value of the variable.

Had to change `var` to `let` as so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < poo.length; i++)
```

Now my variables persist properly all the way down the page and my script can process multiple things at once.

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same problem with you. I call screenshot function every mq task. So when there are many tasks exectute at same time,It will create many Chromium process。My function is here:

```
module.exports = async (_browser, sheetJson) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //goto.page
    const thumbnailPath = path.join('test/out', shortId() + '.png');
    await page.screenshot({
        path: thumbnailPath,
        fullPage: true,
    });
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    return thumbnailPath;
}
```

I think there are too many Chromium process cause memory leak。Beacause every mq task create a browser instance.So I try create a glob browser instance. And I think it works,There are only about five Chromium  process.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the currently shared example indeed, your suspicion is correct: you missed the closing bracket of both: **(1)** the `Screenshot()` function and **(2)** the for loop.

**Example hove to fix them:**

```js
const poo = [
  { PrettyName: 'one', URL: 'https://google.com' },
  { PrettyName: 'two', URL: 'https://google.fr' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < poo.length; i++) {
  console.log('The name of this task is ' + poo[i].PrettyName);
  Screenshot(poo[i].URL);

  async function Screenshot(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      defaultViewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
    });
     // puppeteer methods goes here
  } // ⚠️ closes Screenshot()
}  // ⚠️ closes for loop

console.log('Loop ended succesfully');
```

Which runs as expected.

**Output:**

```
The name of this task is one
The name of this task is two
Loop ended succesfully
```

*Note:* Of course there can be other curly bracket issues in the code, but it would require a bigger part of your code in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to tell.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing this clearly enough - my code did not end there. It just stopped working at that point, so that's all I pasted. The other functions were closed properly further down the page. I found my own answer, which involved using `let` rather than `var` so that my variables persisted.

Comment: thanks for the update! clear, glad that you've found the issue. indeed, it is best to use ES6 features - like `let` and `const` everywhere in Node, that can prevent multiple issues. if you feel sometimes not sure about the code blocks - and you haven't yet used it - I suggest to use a JS linter (like ESlint or JSlint) which can catch lots of syntax errors for you. also can vbe set to notify you if you'd use `var`.

Answer (score -1):

I think in your code you made a little error:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < poo.length; i++) {
    console.log('The name of this task is ' + poo[i].PrettyName); 

    //So far so good! I can output my column names as variables and do what I want with them.

    Screenshot(poo[i].URL);  
    //This works too!

    async function Screenshot(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   headless: true,
   defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080},
   args: [
   "--no-sandbox",
   "--disable-gpu",
   ]
 });
//^
```

You probably and accidentally put `);` at the end of the loop.

Comment: No sir, what you pointed out is closing the `puppeteer.launch` function. That whole chunk is launching a browser to feed commands to later in the loop. Removing it results in a syntax error.